# Is is possible to make a cell non editable based on drop down selection in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I make a non editable cell or Column based on the drop down selection in excel file
Assume I am having 2 values in my drop down as `Hourly` and `Salary`. The other columns I have are `Period Wages` `Rate of Pay` and `Hours`.

If I select `hourly` I would like to enter data only in `Hours` Column, Like that if I select `Salary` I would like to enter data in `Period Wages and Rate of Pay`

Is is possible to do in excel if so can any one help me.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options depending on how sensitive the cells are, and whether you're prepared to write some code.

if you actually want to (lock) the cells, you will need to write VBA code for this, specifically to respond to the Worksheet_Change event.  One example of how to respond to a cell change is [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=36194).  You'd need to write code to protect the appropriate cells based on the changed cell; a more comprehensive example of that is [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-worksheet-functions/657382-conditional-grey-out-and-disabling-of-cells.html).

A simpler alternative would be to use conditional formatting to *gray out* the cells based on a rule, to give the user a visual indication that they shouldn't be changed.  This isn't secure, so if you have many users of the spreadsheet it probably isn't workable - but if you just have a couple of people using it, and you're trying to make their jobs easier, it may do what you want.  There's plenty of examples of this online; one reasonable explanation is [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel).

Comment: Is it possible to do with out code?

Comment: @Dorababu - No, I don't think so, which is the reason I gave the alternate conditional formatting option.  If it's something that's mission-critical, you could also commission someone to write an addon, or adapt the code I linked